# PHP SQL Adding Multiple Selects

Tags: php, sql

I am using the Sql query below:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `venues`

LEFT JOIN `follows` USING (venue_id)
LEFT JOIN `stats` USING (venue_id, user_id)
WHERE follows.user_id = $userid");
```

The problem is that it's not showing some fields in the stats table.

So what I would thinking the problem might be (might be wrong), is that I need to select all the fields of that table?

If this is the case, is there a way of telling it to select * the fields for the 3 tables?

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM `venues`, SELECT * FROM `follows`, SELECT * FROM `stats` LEFT JOIN ....
```

Answer (score 0):

use alias for each table then
    select A.*, B.*, C.* from venues as A left join Follows as B.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias for tables. Here's your request using those aliases:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT a.*, b.*, c.* FROM `venues` as b

LEFT JOIN `follows` as b USING (venue_id)
LEFT JOIN `stats` as c USING (venue_id, user_id)
WHERE follows.user_id = $userid");
```